# CSS Gradient repeats

Tags: html, css, gradient

I've just completed a Django tutorial where I built an ecommerce website, so I am pretty new to HTML and CSS, but I've done Python for quite some time now, so that isn't the problem. So I decided on the website to have a random background color. I could do that quite easily with some JavaScript (edit the CSS value), but that just looked horrible. So I decided to make a random backround with CSS gradient, because that actually looks cool and I want a random color style on my website. Here is the article: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

I have a `body` tag after the panel in the top and in the end of the HTML file.

Here is my CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1));
}
```

Here is an image of the website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/762Mb.png

For some reason it duplicates/repeates itself and I can't figure that out by myself. I have tried making a DIV and asign it the class: grad1 and copy it over from the body tag in the CSS file, but that just does the same thing.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Add `background-repeat:no-repeat`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `background-repeat: no-repeat` to stop the background from repeating.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh; /* Added to display the gradient better */
}
```